# Merging two arrays in PostgreSQL as index and value?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Assuming I have two array fields in a table, like this:

```
 Column |   Type    |
--------+-----------+
 index  | integer[] | 
 value  | integer[] |
```

Where both index and value are equal in length, and the values in 'index' are guaranteed to be unique, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM ArrayTest;
   index   | value             
-----------+-----------------------------------
 {1,3,5,6} | {100, 103, 105, 106}
```

How would I make a query which returns a new array, where the values in 'index' are used as array indexes, and the values in 'value' become the values associated with the given index, i.e. something like:

```
SELECT some_array_function(index, value) as newarray;
            new_array
--------------------------------
{100, NULL, 103, NULL, 105, 106}
```

What I want to achieve is the same as array_combine in PHP.

Comment: This can be probably done in PLPGSQL. But this smells really bad (i.e. bad design) Are you sure you need to do inside your DB such a convoluted thing? (BTW, this is  the same as `array_combine` only when the indexes are integers)

Comment: I agree that it smells. It's somewhat of a desperate attempt to optimize a read-bound application. The new array would be stored in a materialized view, which will only be used for doing certain analysis of the data where I think this design might be an improvement over the current situation.

Comment: I have a project that relies on arrays for one piece of functionality. There are only few array manipulation functions available in Postgres. I was surprised to find that in one case, using a PL/Python function was surprisingly easier and faster than the equivalent SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While overall a bad idea to store data like this, one way to do it is to use the unnest function and the process the results on the client side:

```
SELECT unnest(index), unnest(value) FROM ArrayTest;

 unnest | unnest 
--------+--------
      1 |    100
      3 |    103
      5 |    105
      6 |    106
```

If you must have a function to create a new array here's a short function that will do it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_stitch(index_array integer[], value_array integer[]) RETURNS integer[]
    LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
    AS $$
DECLARE
    ptr INTEGER;
    new_array INTEGER[];
BEGIN
    FOR ptr IN 1..array_upper(index_array,1) LOOP
            new_array[index_array[ptr]] := value_array[ptr];
    END LOOP;

    RETURN new_array;
END;
$$;
```

EDIT:  Here's another way to do it:

```
SELECT array_agg(val order by idx) as output_array
FROM (SELECT generate_series(1,idx[array_upper(idx,1)]) from array_test) as g(idx)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT unnest(idx) as idx, unnest(val) as val FROM array_test\
    ) as data_points USING (idx);
```

Comment: Thank you! The second approach is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_arrays(index INTEGER[], value INTEGER[]) RETURNS INTEGER[] AS $$
DECLARE
    arr_size INTEGER;
    max_index INTEGER;
    result INTEGER[];
    i INTEGER;
    index_pos INTEGER := 1;
BEGIN
    arr_size := array_upper(index, 1);
    max_index := index[arr_size];

    FOR i IN 1..max_index LOOP
        IF index @> ARRAY[i] THEN
            result := result || value[index_pos];
            index_pos := index_pos + 1;
        ELSE
            result := result || '{NULL}'::INTEGER[];
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

    RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Usage:

```
SELECT merge_arrays(index ,value) from array_test;
```